# Finding the direction and value of an induced current using a graph

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image: graph that shows the change in the mangetic field]

A quadratic current loop is inside a magnetic field with the direction shown in the picture. The value of the B field changes like the graph shows. Find the direction and value of the induced current.

Im thinking that the direction is first with the clock, since there will be created a magnetic field going down into the paper because the value of the B field is going down. However then the direction of the current should change after 0.05s as the direction of the magnetic field changes direction (it becomes negative), and because its value is still going down, there should now be created a field that goes up of the plane of the paper. However, the correct answer is that the current keeps going with the clock, but i don't see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that at first the induced current is flowing in an anticlockwise direction.
The induced current produces a magnetic field into the screen thus trying to reduce the effect of the external magnetic field which is also into the screen decreasing.

After the external magnetic field reaches zero it becomes an increasing magnetic field coming out of the screen as the direction of the external magnetic field has been reversed.
What does the induced current have to do?
It has to try and reduce this increasing external magnetic field coming out of the screen.
How does the induced current do that?
It generates a magnetic field which is into the screen.
This is the same direction of magnetic field as the induced current produced at the start.
So the induced current direction stays clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

The induced current tries to maintain the original magnetic field. So when the field into the screen decreases, the induced current is clockwise.

When the magnetic field becomes -ve it changes direction (out of the screen) and increases. But this is the same as a magnetic field into the screen which is still decreasing. So the induced current remains in the same direction clockwise.